# QEntity's setEnabled does not work properly when entities are created in a method called by a signal

Tags: qt, qt5, qt3d, pyside2

`QEntity` which is created in a method called by a signal does not work properly.

Calling method `setEnabled(True)` or `setEnabled(False)` on `QEntity` does not have an effect.

Down below is a working example:

```py
import numpy as np

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QObject, Slot, Signal, QThread
from PySide2.QtGui import QVector3D
from PySide2.Qt3DCore import Qt3DCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QCheckBox, QPushButton,
)
from PySide2.Qt3DExtras import Qt3DExtras


class Worker(QObject):
    @Slot()
    def do_work(self):
        self.sig_done.emit(None)
        self.sig_stopped.emit()

    sig_done = Signal(object)
    sig_stopped = Signal()


class Sphere(Qt3DCore.QEntity):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = []
        self.mesh = Qt3DExtras.QSphereMesh()
        self.mesh.setRadius(.5)
        self.transform = Qt3DCore.QTransform()
        location = np.random.rand(3) * 10
        self.transform.setTranslation(QVector3D(*location))
        self.material = Qt3DExtras.QPhongMaterial(self)

        self.addComponent(self.material)
        self.addComponent(self.mesh)
        self.addComponent(self.transform)

    def toggle(self):
        if self.isEnabled():
            self.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.setEnabled(True)

    def setEnabled(self, is_enabled):
        print("Hello from Sphere!", is_enabled)
        super().setEnabled(is_enabled)


class Spheres(Qt3DCore.QEntity):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.container = [Sphere(self) for _ in range(10)]

    def setEnabled(self, is_enabled):
        print("Hello from Sphere Container!", is_enabled)
        super().setEnabled(is_enabled)


class Window(Qt3DExtras.Qt3DWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 300)
        # Root entity
        self.root_entity = Qt3DCore.QEntity()
        # Camera
        self.cameraEntity = self.camera()
        self.camera().lens().setPerspectiveProjection(45.0, 16.0 / 9.0, 0.1, 1000.0)
        self.camera().setPosition(QVector3D(20.0, 20.0, 20.0))
        self.camera().setUpVector(QVector3D(0, 1, 0))
        self.camera().setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0))
        # For camera controls
        self.camera_controller = Qt3DExtras.QFirstPersonCameraController(self.root_entity)
        self.camera_controller.setCamera(self.camera())

        self.spheres = None
        self.setRootEntity(self.root_entity)

    def load(self):
        self.spheres = Spheres(self.root_entity)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.view = Window()
        self.container = self.createWindowContainer(self.view)

        hLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.vLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        hLayout.addWidget(self.container, 1)
        hLayout.addLayout(self.vLayout)

        self.cb_spheres = None
        self.cb_single_sphere = None

        # ***** These lines cause problems:
        self._thread = QThread()
        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)
        self._worker.sig_stopped.connect(self._thread.quit)
        self._worker.sig_done.connect(self.load)
        self._thread.started.connect(self._worker.do_work)
        self._thread.start()
        # *****

    @Slot()
    def load(self):
        self.view.load()
        self.cb_spheres = QCheckBox(self)
        self.cb_spheres.setChecked(True)
        self.cb_spheres.setText("All spheres")
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.cb_spheres)

        spheres = self.view.spheres

        def func():
            spheres.setEnabled(not spheres.isEnabled())
        self.cb_spheres.stateChanged.connect(func)
        self.cb_single_sphere = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.cb_single_sphere.append(QCheckBox(self))
            self.cb_single_sphere[-1].setChecked(True)
            self.cb_single_sphere[-1].setText("Sphere {}".format(i))
            self.vLayout.addWidget(self.cb_single_sphere[-1])
            self.cb_single_sphere[-1].stateChanged.connect(spheres.container[i].toggle)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    w.resize(1200, 800)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works when I replace lines between `*****` with `self.load()`.

And it neither works when these lines are replaced with:

```
self.btn = QPushButton("Load", self)
self.btn.clicked.connect(self.load)
self.vLayout.addWidget(self.btn)
```

Edit: neither works when these lines are replaced with:

```
self.timer = QTimer()
self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
self.timer.setInterval(1000)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.load)
self.timer.start()
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Just a hint, so that your question doesn't get downvoted or closed: try to provide a minimally working example so that people can see the issue for themselves. Reducing your problem to a minimally working example often already shows what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks, I have added an example.

Comment: I don't see where you set `enabled` to false. Do you set that in the `__init__` function? What I meant by minimally working example is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I.e. users are supposed to be able to copy the code you provide and run it out of the box ;) If I were to copy your code it wouldn't run. Try to break it down a bit more by e.g. just using e.g. Qt's cone mesh (this would reduce the code further and make it more easily comprehensible).

Comment: I cannot add minimally working example. Class `Project` is imported from some third party code written in `C++` wrapped to be used in Python and I do not have access to its source. So this class is also black box for me. `setEnabled` is called from some `QCheckBox`. I added `setEnabled` method into `Points` class. `setEnabled` is always called, but it does not do what it should.

Comment: Ok, here is a suggestion how to proceed when creating minimally working examples: I understand, that you don't have access to the class. But you want to find out where this weird issue comes from. So to create a MWE you could try to omit the `Project` class and instead add two entities (one the parent of the other while the child gets the mesh) in an otherwise blank scene. Then try out if the problem persists. If yes, then you have your minimally working example and found out that the issue is also within simple entities.

Comment: If the problem is gone then try out what happens when you use a custom mesh the way you do in your project - but still without the project class. Create some custom vertex data and set the entity to disabled again. If the problem now arises then it lies within the custom buffer code somehow.

Comment: This is how I proceed when I encounter issues - break them down, and iteratively find the source. But related to your problem: you now have the line `super().setEnabled(is_enabled)  # this does not have an effect` in your code. Above you said this does work, I quote "It works only when setting this on its parent entity.". So does it work when set on the parent or the child entity?

Comment: And to the MWE procedure: If you now find that you can set the entites to disabled and evertything works as expected, then your issue probably lies within the threaded code using the `Project` class. But once you've found out this you can post your question completely different. Then you can say "Ok, it wasn't and issue with Qt3D's code, I tried it out. The problem is within the threads." But even then you can proceed to break down the issue further, but let's get to that point first.

Comment: I tried setting the enabled flag in a very simple C++ example and it worked. This means that this has maybe to do with the threading, but it's hard to tell without being able to experiment with the code.

Comment: @FlorianBlume: Thank you! I have isolated the problem - now I even do not need to use `Project` class. Also I have found another problem - it does not work when we use `QPushButton` to add entities.

Comment: It seems that `QEntity` is not working properly when is created in a method called by a signal.

Comment: Hm the only thing I can think of is that threads are an issue. Maybe try to output the address of the current thread using `qDebug()`, to see if it differs when calling it from the button. But actually this should not be the issue, as the timer fires from the mainthread...

Comment: I created a quick example in which you can add entites through a button and it works perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked (e.g. by displaying a debug message), whether the function `load()` is actually called when pressing the button?

Comment: Yes, when I press a button the method `load()` is called - the spheres are show in the scene. But pressing `QCheckBox`-es do not have an effect except the first one (_All spheres_). One individual sphere cannot be hidden. And yes, `toggle()` is called as well as `setEnabled(...)`.

Comment: @Florian Blume: Have you written your example in `C++` or `Python`?

Comment: https://github.com/Sonnentierchen/Qt3D-Checkboxes I set the entites to be children of the earlier added ones so that you can see that the hierarchy works as well. You can set the entites parents to the root node when creating them in the scene modifier to be able to deactivate them independently. This means there must be some other error in your code which I can't assess as I don't have Qt setup for Python.

Comment: Thanks. But as far I can see the entities in your example are created immediately when application is loaded. This works in my example as well. The problem is if you create entities when application is already running and after a user presses `QPushButton` - then the `QCheckBox`-es do not work.

Comment: You are right, this looks like a bug in Qt3d! I added functionality that the checkboxes and the entites are created dynamically through a button and verified that they work by changing their ambient color. The color gets changed but the entities are still visible... I'll file a bug report. In the mean time, maybe a solution could be - if you know at least the number of objects upfront - to add all entities already and just modify the mesh later. But I don't have time right now to try it out.

Comment: Another idea: check out the Qt3D editor [here](https://github.com/qt-labs/qt3d-editor). I just verified that you can add objects and then disable their visibility. If you find out how they did it you should be able to recreate this functionality.

Comment: The code does work btw if you always specify the root node as the parent. Then you can deactivate each node. Is it an option for you to not add the entities hierarchically?

Comment: OK great, now we have found a bug. Thank you for all the help and filling a report! Yes, now I am trying to modify the entities to have the root node as the parent.